# convergence in distribution of sum of random vectors

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Assume we have a two sequences of random vectors $X_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $Y_{n}\in\mathbb{R}^{d}$ defined on the same probability space and
$$
(X_{n}, Y_{n}) \stackrel{d}{\to} (V, W),
$$
where $(V, W) \in \mathbb{R}^{2d}$ has multivariate normal distribution (possibly degenerate).

Next, let $\alpha: \mathbb{R}^{2d} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta: \mathbb{R}^{2d} \to \mathbb{R}$  be continous differentiable functions and assume that

$$
\alpha(X_{n}, Y_{n}) \stackrel{d}{\to} \beta(V, W).
$$

Is the following true
$$
\alpha(X_{n}, Y_{n})(X_{n} + Y_{n}) \stackrel{d}{\to} \beta(V, W)(V + W)?
$$

Comment: I think $d=1$, $(X_n,Y_n)=(X,Y)\sim\mathcal N(0,I_2)$, $\alpha(v,w):=v$ and $\beta(v,w):=\frac{v+w}{\sqrt2}$ is a counterexample.